# App is crashing while using play games services in unity project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

i am trying to use play games services plugin for unity i have done everything correctly but whenever i am testing it using build and run into my android device it starts to crash but whenever i am removing SignIn(); from start function it's working fine. and also i don't see any sign in window.

my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class PlayServices : MonoBehaviour 
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        // recommended for debugging: 
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        // Activate the Google Play Games platform
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        SignIn();
    }

    public void SignIn()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            if(success){
                Debug.Log("Sign in");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Unable to Sign in");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: show the crash log (exception stacktrace)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i am new to unity and i don't know how to show you crash log... can you tell me how get it?

Comment: that is something you have to learn before starting the development actually.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko For now can you help me with this?

Comment: I unfortunatelty can't as I don't know where you can get the exception stacktrace in Unity. But that is only because I don't use it for development